# Cannot open include file 'afxwin.h':no such header fileor directory in vs 2013 c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, visual-c++-2013

So,I am trying to port some old code to newer version of vs so I imported the sln of the project into my vs 2013 and I get this error and some others and I have gone through some of the other questions on this forum.So I understand that this has something to do with MFC(microsoft foundation classes) but all of them talk about vs 2010 express edition which doesn't include MFC module.I am currently using vs 2013 community edition which is supposed to have full feature access of vs.Still I get this error so please help!!

Thanks!

Comment: So the question is are you sure that afxwin.h is in vs2013? Have you searched your system and is the path to where it resides correct?

Comment: Remove the #include, fix if possible the resulting errors by adding other #include(s).  The MSDN site will tell you which headers are needed for which functions.

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for this prompt response! I have checked in the include folder of vc folder,But I cannot find those headers!! :(

Comment: @Richard Thanks for replying, I did think of that but then again there are too many headers in stdafx.h, So i convinced myself to mark it plan B :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While installing Visual Studio 2013, you need to select the MFC option:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to install those classes without visual studio?